# URL to my module with adminhtml controller

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer, url, forms

I added a form to customer page from backend. How do I create the URL for action attribute to a certain function ( public function editAction(){...} )?
Function that is founded in app/code/local/company/module/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php

Ideeas?

The form is used to set a custom customer attribute created in that module. The form only contains the input and a button for submit. In that particular action I setCustomAttribute and send an email. But every time I submit I get that 404.

This is the layout for my template:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit_tab_view">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>customcustomerfields/customer/tab/view.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

Comment: Please explain "added a form to customer page from backend"; how did you do this?

Comment: @benmarks : but there shoud be a way to construct a link based on module controller action and so on. No?

Comment: what I tried was Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("module/adminhtml_index/edit/")

Comment: Two things. **First:** "I added a form to customer page from backend" - how did you do this? I'm asking because I need to know in what context you are trying to generate the URL. **Second:** are you trying to get the a form which is filled in by the customer to post to an action in an admin controller?

Comment: @benmarks : I added the layout for my template. That should explain what I've done.

Comment: I understand - please add your admin router configuration XML and we can get your question answered. Also, why the custom template?